# How to fix the npm install node-pre-gyp ERR error

Tags: node.js, npm, grpc, yarnpkg

When I run `yarn install` I get the following error, I've deleted the node_modules and yarn.lock files and tried again but no luck, seems to be something with gRPC looking at the error message.

Not sure what to do...  Any suggestions?

```
> grpc@1.10.1 install /Users/mynamegoeshere/Desktop/Projects2/mydemoapp2/mydemoapp/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.1/node-v64-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.16.3 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.16.3 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file 
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
rm: ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o.d.raw: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.
```

Comment: [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1694#issuecomment-474157425) might help you

Comment: are you saying to upgrade protagonist?  I've searched in my package.json file and there's no reference to protagonist??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That version of the `grpc` library is old and is not compatible with that version of Node. You should either use a newer version of `grpc` or an older version of Node. The newest version of `grpc` is currently 1.24.2.

Comment: Tried many different things to solve this error to no avail. This helped to install with yarn.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, a bit different versions. Ubuntu 20.04. A project required Node 10.x, it would not `yarn install`. `yarn.lock` had 2 versions of `grpc` as dependencies, one `grpc` v1.14.1 of `pkgcloud`. But it was errorring on `grpc` v1.9.1, a dependency of `google-gax`. This let me install and build:

- open yarn.lock
- delete a line of the grpc dependency with version on which it errors, save. For example

```
...
google-gax@^0.15.0:
  version "0.15.0"
  ...
  grpc "~1.9.1" <--- deleted this
  ...
```

- run `yarn install --ignore-engines` (I had to use `--ignore-engines`)

This updated some dependencies in `yarn.lock` and removed the section with `grpc@~1.9.1` and project installed and built.