# node-modules installation error in an angular workspace

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

So I have this workspace I have to work on and when I try to use

```
npm install
```

the terminal gives me a bunch of error which I have no idea what these are. I' ealready tried to run as an admin and to delete dthe node_modules folder manually, but nothing works. I've also asked to one of my seniors but even him doesn't know how to resolve this. I've also looked on the internet for a solution but didn't come across it.

The errors are:

```
 node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.0/node-v83-win32-ia32-unknown.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.24.0 and node@14.17.0 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2015
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.10.31321.278) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.19041.0
gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.1684) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.17763.0
gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
gyp ERR! find VS - "2019"
gyp ERR! find VS - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - "2017"
gyp ERR! find VS - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:326:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\sd.workspace\\trunk\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v83-win32-ia32-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\sd.workspace\\trunk\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v83-win32-ia32-unknown" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83" "--python=C:\\Users\\lorenzo.bertolaccini\\.windows-build-tools\\python27\\python.exe" "--msvs_version=2015"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\sd.workspace\trunk\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\sd.workspace\trunk\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-ia32-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\sd.workspace\trunk\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-ia32-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83 --python=C:\Users\lorenzo.bertolaccini\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe --msvs_version=2015' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\sd.workspace\trunk\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\sd.workspace\\trunk\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\sd.workspace\trunk\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\sd.workspace\trunk\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-ia32-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\sd.workspace\trunk\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-ia32-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83 --python=C:\Users\lorenzo.bertolaccini\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe --msvs_version=2015' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\rollup\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\ng-packagr\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.24.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.24.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix the npm install node-pre-gyp ERR error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60692667/how-to-fix-the-npm-install-node-pre-gyp-err-error)

Comment: It looks for VS 2015 specifically to build grpc with, but you have  VS 2019

Comment: I guess there are prebuilt binaries for grpc, but for your Node.js version there isn't one. An option could be to try to find a Node.js version, that has a compatible prebuilt binary.

Answer (score 0):

Run command with `--force --legacy-peer-deps` flags.

```
npm install --force --legacy-peer-deps
```